# Modifing overloaded << operator in ABC C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm currently working on a program that reads json data and displays output to the screen. I have the results displaying in a format that Is satisfactory, but the overloaded << operator doesn't work the way that I need it to. Here are the details of the program.

An istream& of json data containing a list of equations is passed to a factory class. The factories make() method reads the data and creates a std::list of std::unique_ptr based on the equation data in the json file.

The ABC is a class named IEquation. A class called EquationBase is derived from IEquation, and four more classes are derived from EquationBase that implement addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.
In the final for classes, an output() method is implemented. This output method is written as follows.

```
void AddEquation::output(std::ostream& os)
{
   os << getLeftNumber() << " + "
      << getRightNumber() << " = " << getAnswer() << std::endl;
}
```

In IEquation, the stream insertion operator<< is overloaded as follows.

```
// Note: IEquation.output is called to do the work, this method is just a wrapper.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, IEquation& eq)
    {
        eq.output(os);
        return os;
    }
```

I need the following code to work in main

```
void printEquations(std::list<std::unique_ptr<IEquation>>& equations)
{
    for (auto &eq : equations)
    {   
        std::cout << eq;
    }
}
```

Currently, this code displays a memory address for each eq in equations. I can deference eq and get it to display what I need to, but I would like to know why the above printEquations function doesn't work as expected, and what I can do other than dereferencing eq to fix it.

Comment: For anyone wondering, ABC is Abstract Base Class. I had to google it.

Comment: Better than Atomic/Bacterial/Chemical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranged loop is iterating over the objects in the container. And since the objects in the container `equations` are pointers, then `eq` inside the loop will be a pointer.

The overloaded `operator<<` is for `IEquation` *objects* (or rather references to them), not for pointers to `IEquation`, which is why you need to dereference the pointer `eq` inside the loop.

---

If you see e.g. [this range `for` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) you will see the normal non-range `for` loop equivalence.

For your function the equivalent normal `for` loop will be something like

```
for (std::list<std::unique_ptr<IEquation>>::iterator iter = equations.begin(); iter != equations.end(); ++iter)
{
    std::unique_ptr<IEquation>& eq = *iter;

    std::cout << eq;
}
```

In the above loop it's quite clear what the type of `eq` really is.

Comment: Does that mean that overloading the << operator like this should work for the printEquation() function?                                                                                                 
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::unique_ptr<IEquation>& eq)
    {
        eq.output(os);
        return os;
    }

Comment: @Tcrumb It should work, but it's not really what I recommend. Always overload operators with object (or rather const  references to objects).